# TFS Build Error type or namespace doesn't exist

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am getting the following error when building thru tfs: -

The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

xxx is a com dll so I registered the dll on the build server it still doesn't work.

I noticed the Com+ Server Windows Service wasn't running so I ran it still no joy.

I have tried registering the dll with both regsvr32 standard and the syswow located dll.

I am running out of options, please help.

The build server is a virtual server running Windows 2008 and I am running tfs-2010. I am also running the build account as an administrator (for testing) so its not a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ComReferences to ComFileReferences seemed to get over the compilation issue.